# Como hacer una cuenta regresiva en PHP MYSQL?

Tags: php

Tengo que elaborar un sistema en el que cuando un usuario de la web suba un archivo imagen a la base de datos esta misma persona no pueda subir otro archivo si no hasta pasadas las 24 horas del primer archivo que subió (Esto para evitar que suba spam).

Nunca eh hecho esto y algunos me dan solución en JAVASCRYPT pero necesito que sea en backend.

**Solo necesito saber si esto es posible para ponerme a buscar como desarrollarlo solo que vengo a preguntar si es posible lo que pregunto o si estoy equivocado.**

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Si, es posible. Un usuario tiene o debería tener un identificador único en tu sistema, digamos que es el correo. Si un usuario autenticado en tu sistema, sube un archivo, deberías poder almacenar en una base de datos esa acción, asociando al usuario por su identificador y generando un timestamp del momento en que se realiza la acción. Si este mismo usuario desea subir otro archivo, el sistema sólo lo permitirá si la diferencia de tiempo entre  el timestamp de la última acción asociada a este usuario y la nueva, es superior al límite mínimo permitido. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Lo que se me ocurre que podrías hacer es, guardar la fecha y hora (TimeStamp) en que el usuario guardo la imagen (no se si esto ya lo hagas) y después, al momento de guardar la información del nuevo registro, revisar si ya pasaron las 24 horas, por ejemplo:

```
//Aqui va tu codigo para sacar la informacion de la base de datos
$FechaDeGuardado = "2022-10-03 03:55:06";//Por ejemplo que recibiera esta fecha

if(Pasaron24Horas($FechaDeGuardado)){
//Tu codigo para guardar
}else{
//Otra cosa
}
```

y la funcion

```
function Pasaron24Horas($FechaDeGuardado){
            date_default_timezone_set("America/Mexico_City");//En mi caso que estoy en mexico asigno la zona horaria
            $FechaDeGuardado = date( $FechaDeGuardado);//Convierto el valor a foramato de fecha
            $Hoy= date("Y-m-d H:i:s");    //Tomo la fecha actual
            
            $Diferencia = $FechaDeGuardado -> diff($Hoy);//Ver cuanto tiempo ha pasado
             $DiferenciaHoras = $Diferencia->h;  //Convertirlo a horas
             
             if($DiferenciaHoras>24){$Resultado=true;}else{$Resultado=false;}
             
             return $Resultado;
}
```

Comment: Agradezco mucho tu ayda (También al compañero). Estoy trabajando en **PHP** y parece que tu solución se acomoda (Y de manera sencilla) a lo que estoy buscando implementar. Si esto funciona te estaré agradecido para siempre (Gracias a las respuestas a todos).